# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in [MKMapView setShowsUserLocation]

Tags: ios, mapkit, exc-bad-access

I'm getting the nasty EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a relatively straightforward piece of code. Does any one have any idea why this code crashes?

```
stack:
_remove ()
-[MKQuadTrie remove:] ()
-[MKAnnotationContainerView removeAnnotation:] ()
-[MKMapView(UserPositioningInternal) removeUserLocation] ()
-[MKMapView(UserPositioning) stopUpdatingUserLocation] ()
-[MKMapView setShowsUserLocation:] ()
-[MapViewController stopTrackingLocation]

code:
- (void)stopTrackingLocation 
{
    if (mapView.showsUserLocation)
    {
        // Crashes here
        mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am having the same issue.

Comment: This stack trace would be far more useful if it were complete rather than abbreviated. A lot of people search the exact crash text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie but I'm just trying to help. 
Is your application failing at the point where you just start your app? 
I think it shows bad access because getting your location takes time, and you access it before your gps get the location data.
So to prevent this I will use the didupdatetolocation: method. 
Assign the location data into "something"

so if "something" is not nil, then only mapview.showsuserlocation = NO;

Comment: This is the sort of the workaround I used to get around this framework issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error you use to get when you try access non existing object. Are you sure `mapView` was not released from memory before `- stopTrackingLocation` call?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the map view is still a valid object.